# Using resources across CDK apps

Tags: aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

According to the [best practices for the CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html), runtime code and infrastructure code should reside next to each other in the same repository.
In my case I have a few resources that are used across multiple projects, e.g. a Cognito user pool. These resources I've put into a separate repository for common infrastructure.

Now when I want to use this infrastructure in my other projects (in a separate repository), I could import it via ARN. But because the other resources is also managed by a stack, I can't rely on the ARN staying the same. How do I go about importing these resources? What are best practices to handle this situation (which I would imagine to be quite common, especially in microservice architectures, etc., but I find very little infortmation about it)?

What I've tried and considered:

Import via ARN:

- stack might need to be reconfigured reguarly
- probably causes probelms that are difficult to debug

Export ARN in first app (CfnOutput), import in second app (Fn.importValue):

- when updating the export, stack is rolled back because the Output is in use and can't be deleted

Using only one CDK app for infrastructure:

- goes against best practices

Comment: You could use secrets manager to store the changing ARNs. Then you could use the secret store name (shouldn't change), to import the values.

Comment: @Luke That would mean that the stacks that depend on those values wouldn't automatically update when the value in the secret store changes, right?